# String[] array is getting converted into List in Google GSON

Tags: java, json, hashmap, gson

May I know the reason why my `String[]` array is getting converted into List Array in below example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     String s1="one,two";
     Map<String, String[]> m =new HashMap<String, String[]>();
     m.put("attribute" , s1.split(","));
     String[] s = ( String[]) m.get("attribute"); // this works fine 

    Gson gson=new Gson();
    String se = gson.toJson(m);
      HashMap hm = gson.fromJson(se, HashMap.class);
      String[] sArray  = ( String[]) hm.get("attribute"); //this give exception cant convert list into String array 
      List lst  = ( List) hm.get("attribute"); // this works fine 

}
```

I am using Google's GSON Class.

Comment: is it possible to provide json content ??

Comment: What kind of exception is being thrown? That should give you some insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type Gson deserializes an array JSON type is a List.  If you want it to create an array of a primitive type you need to write your own object which would be a class that contains a primitive array called 'attribute'

```
public class MyObject {
    protected String[] attribute;
}
```

and provide a serializer/deserializer for your type.  See: https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeAdapter-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.Object-